# 0;95;0c escape code is inserted with typeahead in terminal emacs

Tags: terminal-emacs

Whenever I start the terminal emacs and there is typeahead (i.e., I start typing before emacs starts), the escape code `0;95;0c` gets inserted into the buffer. For example, if I run

```
sleep 3; emacs -Q test
```

and type `qwerty` while the sleep is happening (`test` is a new file), the buffer will open with

```
qwerty0;95;0c
```

The `*Messages*` buffer says

```
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
(New file)
M-[ > is undefined
Making completion list...
```

My `$TERM` is `xterm-256color` and I am using iTerm2 on OS X 10.10.5.

*EDIT: If I use Terminal.app instead of iTerm2, I get `1;2c` in place of `0;95;0c` and it opens a help buffer with "Global bindings starting with M-[". Not sure what key sequence activates that.*

How can I determine what this escape code is and make it not get inserted into my emacs buffers?

Comment: The reason is probably the mismatch between declared and actual terminal. Try using "correct" values for `$TERM`: `iterm` for iTerm, and `nsterm` for Terminal.app.

Comment: Is `iterm` a real `TERM`? When I do that emacs won't start (`Cannot open terminfo database file`).

Comment: Try `iTerm.app`; it's an alias. Or look into `/usr/share/terminfo/i/` (or the MacOSX equivalent) and see if there is anything adequate there.

Comment: I'm really not following what you're suggesting. Also note that I'm using iTerm2, not iTerm (which is defunct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. It is coming from the `xterm-extra-capabilities` setting, which by default does a check, which [sends](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/306a6f8d435e8283691898552391687aeff4110d/lisp/term/xterm.el#L796) the `"\e[>0c"` code. I can confirm that `echo -e "\e[>0c"` in iTerm2 prints `0;95;0c` to the typeahead. See also http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html (search for `CSI > Ps c`).

Customizing `xterm-extra-capabilities` and setting the capabilities manually makes the problem go away.

I'm not clear if this is a bug in iTerm2 or emacs (I don't know how to debug the terminal to see if it is sending the CSI codes properly).

Comment: Does changing `xterm-query-timeout` affect anything?

Comment: @npostavs interesting. It seems it does. However, there must be some bug here. If I set it to some very large number, like `30` (the default value is `2`), I still get the `0;95;0c` (my emacs takes maybe 3-5 seconds tops to start). But if I set it to `nil` the bug goes away. I'm worried there could be adverse side effects to removing the timeout, though. Usually timeouts are there for a reason.

Comment: There is a comment in `xterm--query` saying "Maybe we could always use the asynchronous approach, but it's less tested." In other words, the timeout was left in because of worries about adverse side effects. But there aren't any *known* problems for the asynch method (as far as I can see).

Comment: In what character did you set `xterm-extra-capabilities`? (`nil`?)