# How can I prevent `84;0;0c` written into first line when emacs daemon starts running?

Tags: daemon

When emacs frozen, I restart it and I see that `84;0;0c` may end up writting into very first line of the latest open file.

---

The way I start emacs daemon: `emacsclient -c -qut file.txt 2>/dev/null`. While this process is on-going when I type enter or some characters they show up on the opened file.

```bash
$ cat file.txt
MY_FILE_STARTS
$ kill -9 $(ps auxww | grep -E "[e]macsclient"  | awk '{print $2}')
$ emacsclient -qut file.txt 2>/dev/null
alper
alper
alper
```

Than opened file shown as follows:

```
lper
alper
alper


84;0;0cMY_FILE_STARTS
```

Simple solution would be not to enter any keys while emacs daemon is starting but accidently I may end up typing enter once in a while.

What does `84;0;0c` stands for and is it possible to prevent writing those characters when emacs is unresponsive?

Comment: Have you tried to interrupt Emacs from some shell command line via `pkill -SIGUSR2 emacs`? That should start the debugger. It may be necessary to call `pkill -SIGUSR2 emacs` multiple times.

Comment: Yes but when emacs freeze and when I try to exit from the daemon or press some keys they written into buffer and shows up after the emacs starts working

Comment: @Tobias I figure out the reason for this. I was starting emacs daemon as follows: `emacsclient -qut 2>/dev/null` after this when I press any key like enter that writting into 1st line of the open file followed by `84;0;0c`

Comment: This is probably not an Emacs problem. What terminal emulator are you using? Do you get the same results if you use xterm instead?

Comment: I am using iTerm2(https://iterm2.com) ; same problem occurs in Terminal

Comment: I don't have this problem on macOS, iTerm2 and Emacs 28.1

Comment: I suggest you divide and test your Emacs and ZSH related config.

Comment: @TianshuWang This is not related to `zsh` ; it happens with `bash` as well.

Comment: What do the emacsclient options `-qut` do? I don't find them in my `emacsclient` man page at all. As for "starting the emacs daemon", I don't understand what you mean: emacsclient cannot start the daemon - instead you start *emacs* with `--daemon` and it runs in the background without a frame, but starts a server to listen. Then you invoke `emacsclient` to connect to the server. In short, I don't think you are describing the situation you are facing accurately enough, so nobody can figure out what's really happening, let alone fix it.

Comment: FWIW, I guess somebody is issuing an ANSI escape sequence (e.g. 'ESC [ 84;0;0c`) but I cannot find one that ends in `c`.

Comment: issuing at emacs repo?  Should I ask this question in https://unix.stackexchange.com  since seems like this issue could be resolved by correct usage of linux commands

Comment: @NickD my problem was related to following question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16878/0950c-escape-code-is-inserted-with-typeahead-in-terminal-emacs/41004#41004  . Seems like I just had to do: `(setq xterm-extra-capabilities nil)`

Comment: Write it up as an answer and accept it (after the waiting period).

Comment: @NickD done hope my answer will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in [0;95;0c escape code is inserted with typeahead in terminal emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16878/0950c-escape-code-is-inserted-with-typeahead-in-terminal-emacs/41004#41004) and [Everytime I open emacs with -nw my file is prepended with 0;276;0c. My screen realestate is also being cut in half](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21721/18414).

My problem was:

> **This is more likely to happen if you are using Emacs over a slow connection, and begin typing before Emacs is ready to respond.**

Solution:

> Customizing `xterm-extra-capabilities` and setting the capabilities
> manually makes the problem go away. But if I set it to nil the bug
> goes away.

I had to add: `(setq xterm-extra-capabilities nil)` into my init file to fix this problem.